# How to loop for controls, in multi user controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls, foreach

I want to ask if I can loop in my controls, like textbox, dropdown list or etc, in which they are in a page's user control. The scenario is that, assume I have a page called 'Page.aspx' and I have 3 user controls in that `page(uc1, uc2 and uc3)` and an asp panel (named PnlTab1) to contain all these controls in each user control.
I am using that code to reach my controls:

---

```
            UserControl uc1, uc2, uc3;
            uc1 = usercontrol1;
            uc2 = usercontrol2;
            uc3 = usercontrol3;

            foreach (Control c in uc1.FindControl("PnlTab1").Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
            }

            foreach (Control c in uc2.FindControl("PnlTab1").Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
            }
            foreach (Control c in uc3.FindControl("PnlTab1").Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                    ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
            }
```

---

Now, I do not want to write each time '`foreach (Control c in uc3.FindControl("PnlTab1").Controls`' . Can I recursively do that?

Thank you all a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for recursion, just another loop:

```
   UserControl[] ucs = new UserControl[3]{
         usercontrol1,
         usercontrol2,
         usercontrol3
   };
   foreach (UserControl uc in ucs){
        foreach (Control c in uc.FindControl("PnlTab1").Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Tim, Dave and TheGeekYouNeed.

Comment: I cannot declare user controls as an array. There are so many errors occuring when i try this. Unfortunately, I am remote connecting to my program and I have connection problems. I will try this again tomorrow. Thank you for your answer Tim.

Comment: sorry, I flashed back to c there. This new syntax should be right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it recursively.

Pass in the container for your controls (Page is a valid Control)

```
    public static void DisableAllChildServerControls(Control ctrl, bool disable)
    {
        foreach(Control c in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox t = c as TextBox;
                t.Enabled = !disable;
                if (t.ID == "txtRefundedAmount")
                    t.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (c is DropDownList)
            {
                DropDownList d = c as DropDownList;
                d.Enabled = !disable;
            }
            else if (c is Button)
            {
                Button b = c as Button;
                b.Enabled = !disable;
            }

            if(c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                DisableAllChildServerControls(c, disable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have some connection problems for my remote connection, and I will try it again later. I will share the result. Thanks a lot again..!

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't (to the best of my knowledge) support a recursive FindControl, but it can be implemented yourself.  Steve Smith has one:  [Recursive FindControl](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/recursive-findcontrol/)

It has the added benefit of using generics, so you could do something like:

```
// uc3 has id = "UserControl1"
TextBox tb = FindControl<TextBox>(UserControl1, "PnlTab1");
if (tb != null)
{ 
    tb.Enabled = true;
}
```

Take a look at his article and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have some connection problems for my remote connection, and I will try it again later. I will share the result. Thanks a lot again..!